# How can I invert this color space transformation?

Tags: matlab, colors

I have this function I am trying to invert:

```
XYZ2LMSmat = [0.3593 -0.1921 0.0071; 0.6976 1.1005 0.0748; -0.0359 0.0754 0.8433];
LMS2ICTCPmat = [2048 2048 0; 6610 -13613 7003; 17933 -17390 -543]'/4096;

invEOTF = @(Lin) (((3424/4096)+(2413/128)*(max(0,Lin)/10000).^(2610/16384)) ./ ...
(1+(2392/128)*(max(0,Lin)/10000).^(2610/16384))).^(2523/32);

ICTCP = bsxfun(@times, invEOTF(XYZ * XYZ2LMSmat) * LMS2ICTCPmat, [720, 360, 720]);
```

This script converts from XYZ to ICtCp color space. Input (`XYZ`) takes the format of an N by 3 (rgb) matrix that is multiplied by the 3x3 transform matrices `XYZ2LMSmat` and `LMS2ICTCPmat`.

I am trying to write the reverse: going from ICtCp to XYZ.

I have the inverse function of the `invEOTF` function, which is:

```
EOTF = @(PQ) (max(PQ.^(32/2523)-(3424/4096),0) ./ ... ((2413/128)-(2392/128)*PQ.^(32/2523))).^(16384/2610)*10000;
```

[Here is the reference for this code](https://www.dolby.com/us/en/technologies/dolby-vision/measuring-perceptual-color-volume-v7.1.pdf), which goes into more detail (Matlab code found at end of doc).

I am unsure of which flag for `bsxfun` I should use and how to arrange the matrix inversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it beneficial to split up operations, it makes it easier to see what they do and figure out how to reverse them. This is your computation:

```matlab
step1 = XYZ * XYZ2LMSmat;
step2 = invEOTF(step1);
step3 = step2 * LMS2ICTCPmat;
ICTCP = bsxfun(@times, step3, [720, 360, 720]);
```

We can now reverse these steps:

```matlab
step3_back = bsxfun(@times, ICTCP, 1./[720, 360, 720]);
step2_back = step3_back / LMS2ICTCPmat;
step1_back = EOTF(step2_back);
XYZ_back = step1_back / XYZ2LMSmat;
```

We can compare `step3` to `step3_back`, `step2` to `step2_back`, and `step1` to `step1_back`, if `XYZ_back` is not equal to `XYZ`, to figure out where  things go wrong.

I noticed that, where `step2_back` is zero, `step1_back` does not match `step1`. This happens where `step1` is negative. `step1_back` remains zero. This is due to the explicit clipping through `max` in `EOTF`. This happened when X was close to 1, and Y was close to 0 (I tested this with random values for XYZ in the range [0,1]).

---

Do note that `bsxfun` is usually no longer necessary with MATLAB R2016b and newer. You can simply write `ICTCP = step3 .* [720, 360, 720]`.

Comment: Amazing Cris, thank you for helping me this has made my day!